# Best cover for IR proximity sensor?

Tags: infrared

What would be the best type of cover/front panel for a circuit board that has an IR proximity sensor consisting of an IR LED and an IR photdiode? Would regular plastic/plexiglass work or would that reflect the emitted IR too much and screw up the proximity detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will reflect very little IR back on the sensor as long as the window is perpendicular to the travel of light.  You can enhance this by shrouding the sensor or emitter right up to the window with something that doesn't pass IR light.

While a little will come back due to the window, the difference between that small reflection and a reflection from an external object should be so great that detection isn't a problem.